# How to I wait for element to be displayed for (Shadow-root) element

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

In Selenium; How can I wait until this element gets loaded on the screen?

```js
document.querySelector('dps-app')
        .shadowRoot.querySelector('dps-home-auth')
        .shadowRoot.querySelector('dps-instance-sidebar')
        .shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('dps-link')[0].innerText
```

Comment: Is the shadow root open? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/mode Also, unless you have deeply nested shadow roots, why are there so many properties called 'shadowRoot" in your chain?

Comment: because it has multiple hidden nodes... The above path what ever i mentioned it is working fine. But how can I get that element through code during execution.

Comment: You could set a ``MutationObserver`` **MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver